# How to configure white balance on a light table?

Tags: white-balance

I am currently photographing large aerial (300mmx260mm) transparencies on a light table using an Olympus E-420 and spirit level. How would I best set up the white balance of such a set up?

Comment: What problems did you experienced?

Comment: well...I guess my only problem is that I don´t know whether the white-balance is accurate or distorting the colours in my picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a "blank" transparency, set that on the light table, and then take a shot of that to use as the basis for white balancing in post. Since both the light in the table and the transparency medium can cause a color cast, combine those two elements. If you don't have a blank transparency, see if there's any "clear" spots in any of the transparencies you're using, and possibly use that area.

Systematically shoot in RAW, so that you can white balance in post, rather than attempt to do it in-camera. If you're using Adobe Camera RAW, or Lightroom's Develop module, you can white balance the "clear" shot, and then apply the same setting to all your images systematically.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

1. take off any transparencies
2. point your camera to the center of the table, so a detail of the table fills the frame
3. Adjust your aperture (probably increase the F-number), so the resulting photo is not white, but middle gray
4. Take a photo
5. Either in camera or in some application (Lightroom?) sample the color to get accurate White balance.